# with SVM, are incorrectly classified training points support vectors?

Tags: svm

I always thought $\alpha_i \neq 0$ implied that $i$ was a support vector. However, now that I think about it, I am confused. If a training point is incorrectly classified, it will have a non-null $\alpha$, does it make sense to use it for classifying new points? Do we use it to compute the optimal separating hyperplane? Is the classifier different from one trained without that point?

Answer (score 1):

If a training pattern is incorrectly classified, it will indeed be a support vector, because patterns that are not support vectors must be on the "right" side of the margin, and the decision boundary is on the "wrong" side of that margin.